# Basis of kernel linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

For this matrix $A$ acting on $V = \mathbb{R}^3$
\begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & 1 & 0\\
  1 &  0 & 1\\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Find a basis for $\ker(A + I)^2$ and for $\ker(A - I)$ and who that these subspaces are $T_A$-Invariant

Show that $V$ is the direct sum of the above two $T_A$-Invariant subspaces.

Display the matrix of $T_A$ relative to this new basis.

Could anyone walk me through this question? It's a sample question for my upcoming midterm. I'm not too sure about showing subspaces of $T_A$-invariant.

Thanks

Comment: How does $A$ act on $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Can you at least do the first steps? Are you able to find the appropriate basis vectors and to Jordanize the matrix?

Comment: What does TA-invariant mean? Did you mean A-invariant?

Comment: Sorry I meant $T_A$ Invariant where it is a linear transformation.
I can find the basis vectors. Is it necessary to jordanize it?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand $T_A$-invariant either. What do you mean by that? And no, you do not have to Jordanize to do this. You can simply solve the corresponding linear systems by Gauss elimination if you want.

Comment: By $T_A$, do you mean the linear map $T_A(x)=Ax$?

Comment: It just means it's invariant to  transformations. The transformation of a vector space on itself will result in the same vector space. If W is T-invariant, we can restrict T to W to arrive at a new linear mapping
T|W : W → W.

Comment: Sorry but his does not make any sense. You must be talking about invariance under the transformation $A:\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, or $T_A$ if you want to call it that way. But certainly not under any transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A+I=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\1&1&1\\1&0&1}$. Now since a matrix with columns $[v_1\ v_2\ \dots]$ multiplied (from right) by a vector $\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\ \vdots}$ yields $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots$, it is easily seen that already for $v_1:=\pmatrix{1\\0\\-1}$
$$(A+I)v_1=0\, ,$$
so $v_1\in\ker(A+I)\subseteq\ker(A+I)^2$.

Now $(A+I)^2=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\2&2&2\\1&1&1}$. Now all columns are the same, and besides $v_1$, we easily find that $v_2:=\pmatrix{1\\-1\\0}$ also satisfies $(A+I)^2v_2=0$, and is clearly independent from $v_1$. The image of $(A+I)^2$ contains exactly the multiples of $\pmatrix{1\\2\\1}$, hence it has dimension $1$, so $\dim\ker(A+I)^2=2$, and we already found a basis: $v_1,v_2$.

For $A$-invariance, calculate $Av_1$ and $Av_2$. We get $Av_1=-v_1$ (also because $(A+I)v_1=0$), and $Av_2=-v_1-v_2$. So, this subspace $\ker(A+I)^2=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ is invariant under the action of $A$.

$A-I=\pmatrix{-2&1&0\\1&-1&1\\1&0&-1}$. Now, calculating by columns, for getting $0$ as their combination, add the first column to the third, plus twice the middle one: 
$$v_3:=\pmatrix{1\\2\\1}, \quad (A-I)v_3=0$$
$v_3$ is independent from $v_1$ and $v_2$ because, either you can check that $(A+I)^2v_3\ne 0$, or we can argue that that the coordinates of all vectors in $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ sum up to $0$, so $v_3\notin\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$.
Then, the direct composition of all the 3d space is given:
$$\Bbb R^3=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle \oplus\langle v_3\rangle$$
We  also need $Av_3$ for its matrix in the new basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$, but it is just $v_3$, because $(A-I)v_3=0$. So, its matrix in the new basis is:
$$\pmatrix{-1&-1&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1}$$
(the middle column represents that $Av_2=-v_1-v_2$).

For completeness, let me add that if $B=\left[v_1\ v_2\ v_3\right]$, then this (almost Jordan formed) matrix in the new basis is just $B^{-1}AB$.